# Can I remelt flux paste?

Tags: solder-paste

I have a container with flux paste.
It is not very practical so I would like to transfer it to a syringe.

Can I simply melt it by heating it (double heater with water)?

It is also pointed out that sometimes I used the iron directly in the paste for cleaning so here and there there are puddles of water, which usually disappears when I leave the container open, but still could be embedded in some pockets.

Comment: There should absolutely not be puddles of water after dipping your iron's tip in the paste!

Comment: I've used out of date solder paste by mixing it with iso-propyl alcohol. It might work with flux.